# Nativescript angular 2 how to place custom splash screen and load background datas while splash screen in the view(Both android and ios)

Tags: angular2-nativescript

Hi iam using native script angular 2.i am new to this technology.i want to change the splash screen and also i want to do some background operations when the splash screen is on the display.i want the solution to support for both android and ios.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin if it's fit your need : [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-splashscreen)